# How to replace all available special character and numbers in php using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am using AES algorithm and its encrypting the string with all avilable special chanracter and number. Please help me to write a ereg_replace function which will remove all special character and number from the encrypted string.

Example of the string is:

```
HyS7Nj+c3b3+1kaT6gLpK9kDQS3lIDtYUNQHtz/bLAw=
```

i have used following:

```
    $enc1 = preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '', $enc);
$enc2=preg_replace('/[\/\&%#\$]/', '', $enc1);
$en=preg_replace('/[\"\'\|]/', '', $enc2);
```

Every time this string it gets change. so please help me. i want to replace this with any random character.

help me to write one single preg_replace which will just give me alphabets in resulted string.

Comment: why would you do that? This doesn't serve any purpose, or I'm not getting something.

Comment: Please provide the expected output for your example string "HyS7Nj+c3b3+1kaT6gLpK9kDQS3lIDtYUNQHtz/bLAw=".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

To remove just special characters use this.

```
$enc = "HyS7Nj+c3b3+1kaT6gLpK9kDQS3lIDtYUNQHtz/bLAw=";
echo preg_replace('/\W/', '', $enc);
```

To remove both numbers and special characters use this.

```
$enc = "HyS7Nj+c3b3+1kaT6g$#@LpK9kDQS3lIDtYU%^NQHtz/bLAw=";
echo preg_replace('/\W|\d/', '', $enc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following regex

```
[^a-zA-Z]
```

Using `preg_replace` like as

```
$enc = "HyS7Nj+c3b3+1kaT6gLpK9kDQS3lIDtYUNQHtz/bLAw=";
echo preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $enc);
```

**Explanation :** The above regex  will capture all those characters which are not alphabets

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/2DXVK)

Comment: how can i make sure that 44 character should be = symbol

Comment: or i can say last symbol should be = sign

Comment: Didn't get you what you mean to say

Comment: $enc="HyS7Nj+c3b3+1kaT6gLpK9kDQS3lIDtYUNQHtz/bLAw="

Comment: String ends with equal to symbol. so i want after removing special char and number, the string should end with equal to sign

Comment: simply use `$replaced_string."="`

Comment: Downvoters post the reason behind downvoting. It's better to improve answer instead of deleting an answer